# SQL Server : need a query

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables -

```
Table_1
accid0v    fcustn0v

1210001       A
1210002       B
1210003       C

Table_2
accid0v    cases0v

1210001     Open
1210001     Open
1210001   Resolved
1210002   Resolved
1210003     Open

Table_3
accid0v     actd0v

1210001     2/16/2014
1210002     4/5/2014
1210003     6/8/2014
```

i want to show data like this

```
accid0v  fcustn0v   actd0v   Total  Open

1210001    A       2/16/2014   3      2
1210002    B       4/5/2014    1      0
1210003    C       6/8/2014    1      1
```

I am using sql server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fairly straight forward `JOIN` with a `GROUP BY` will do it;

```
SELECT 
  a.accid0v, a.fcustn0v, c.actd0v,
  COUNT(*) total, SUM(CASE WHEN b.cases0v='open' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Open]
FROM table_1 a 
JOIN table_2 b ON a.accid0v = b.accid0v
JOIN table_3 c ON a.accid0v = c.accid0v
GROUP BY a.accid0v, a.fcustn0v, c.actd0v
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25e53/1).

Comment: Can we do this without using SUM - CASE WHEN... ? Thanks.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev Any particular reason? There are multiple ways to write the query, but I'm not quite sure what you're looking for.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - I was wondering if a DB does not have CASE, then how to make it work, OR try to mimic the case myself.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev You mean something like [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/da900/1)? (Although I can't think of any SQL database without CASE)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - Thanks, that is exactly what I meant. Can you add that to your answer or should I ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my first thought

```
select 
   t1.accid0v
   ,t1.fcustn0v
   ,t3.actd0v
   ,sum(case when t2.cases0v='Open' then 1 else 0 end) as open
   ,sum(0) as total 
from table_1 as t1
join table_2 as t2 on t2.accid0v=t1.accid0v
join table_3 as t3 on t3.accid0v=t1.accid0v
group by 1,2,3
```

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` syntax won't (as far as I can tell) work on SQL Server.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - I get an error - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'open'.